# Plugin to use masonry "on demmand"

Tags: jquery, html, image, jquery-masonry

I have a page that have a growing number of images. Just like a gallery, and I'm using `Masonry` and `Lightbox` to sort it, and give it a gallery aspect. The website it's pretty much just a bunch of Images, and i want the images to fit in each other (masonry can handle it). But the gallery is growing, (1000+ images already), therefore, the page is starting to take a long time to sort it up. Is there a js plugin that allow me to do the masonry sort up, and load the tumbnails for the images later? Like On Demand. Or when reaching the page's bottom, start to load another set of images...

Any one to point me one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this example?
http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html

Comment: Shame on me! How could i not see it. Thank you